# SQL Oracle Query self query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to figure out how to populate the below NULL values with 1.245 for dates from `07-OCT-14` to `29-SEP-14` then from `26-SEP-14` to `28-JUL-14` it will be 1.447.

This means if the date is less than or equal to the given date then use the value of max effective date which is less than the given date

We could select the last available index_ratio value for given security_alias and effective date <=p.effective_date , so in other words we will need to modify the sql to return from the subquery the index ratio value identified for the maximum available effective date assuming that this effective date is less or equal position effective date

How to populate the value ?

```
select ab.security_alias,
ab.index_ratio,
ab.effective_date
from securitydbo.security_analytics_fi ab 
where ab.security_alias = 123627
order by ab.effective_date desc
```

[image]

Below should be the output

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what is the input and expected results here.

Comment: It's not clear what *the below NULL values* actually are

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your requirements correctly, I think the analytic function LAST_VALUE() is what you're after. E.g.:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 id, 10 val, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                     select 1 id, null val, to_date('02/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                     select 1 id, null val, to_date('03/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                     select 1 id, null val, to_date('04/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                     select 1 id, 20 val, to_date('05/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                     select 1 id, 21 val, to_date('06/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                     select 1 id, null val, to_date('07/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                     select 1 id, null val, to_date('08/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                     select 1 id, 31 val, to_date('09/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                     select 1 id, null val, to_date('10/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                     select 1 id, 42 val, to_date('11/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual)
select id,
       last_value(val ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by dt) val,
       dt
from   sample_data
order by id, dt desc;

        ID        VAL DT        
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         42 11/08/2015
         1         31 10/08/2015
         1         31 09/08/2015
         1         21 08/08/2015
         1         21 07/08/2015
         1         21 06/08/2015
         1         20 05/08/2015
         1         10 04/08/2015
         1         10 03/08/2015
         1         10 02/08/2015
         1         10 01/08/2015
```